# How to set logging level of processed in pool from the main process?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have set logging config in the main process:

```
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

After this I am using multiprocessing Pool. For code executed by the pool, only logs with level greater than WARNING are getting printed. Is there any way to set the logging level of the processes in the pool from the main process?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the log level as an argument to the child process call.
In the child process, initialize a new logger with the passed log level.